# Jenkins: What is better to use? Crumb or Authentication Token?

Tags: jenkins, access-token, restful-authentication, jenkins-api

To trigger a job remotely via script: Jenkins provides two mechanisms.

One is Jenkins generated Crumb - common for all jobs.

Other option is manually created Authentication Token - can be unique for all jobs.

Which of these two option is preferred and why?

Answer (score 3):

By itself - none.

The crumb is used to [prohibit CSRF attacks](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/CSRF+Protection), and is no mean by which to trigger a job remotely. A token can be considered an additional password for certain jobs, and if set, needs to be passed when triggering that job.

You can trigger a job remotely by using the [Remote API](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/jenkins/remote+access+api), which boils down to a HTTP request. There surely are other means, e.g. the [Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Remote+Trigger+Plugin) etc.